# OpenCV: lossless capture?

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a simple python program that uses OpenCV and scantailor-cli to scan documents with my document camera and store them as high-contrast, low filesize PDFs.

Approach:

1. capture the document in full color with OpenCV at 1920x1080 in JPG format
2. convert to high-contrast black-and-white PDF with scantailor-cli

This generally works, however I have discovered an issue with my usage of OpenCV that is limiting the quality of my scans.  I'm hoping someone here can give me the nudge I need to improve this.

When I use the UI-based capture software that came with my IPEVO document camera (Visualizer), I get a nice, clearn capture that makes a great conversion into high-contrast.  When I use OpenCV, I get unwanted compression artifacts and conversion to high-contrast yields unsatisfactory results.

[image: Comparison of image capture quality between IPEVO Visualizer and OpenCV. You should be able to see more compression artifacts in the OpenCV image.]

Full program listing is here: https://github.com/jonashw/Document-Scanner/blob/master/scan.py

Relevant excerpt below

```
def do_camera(device_id):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(device_id)#,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    w,h = 1920,1080
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, w)
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, h)
    cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT, 0)
    w = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    h = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    grab_mode = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE)
    format = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FORMAT)
    print("capturing with w={}, h={}, grab_mode={}, format={}".format(w,h,grab_mode, format))
    
    #ok = False
    #i = -100
    #while (not ok) and i < 10:
        #if i != 0:
            #print("setting grab_mode {}".format(grab_mode + i))
            #ok = cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE, grab_mode + i)
        #i += 1
    #if ok:
        #gm = cam.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_MODE)
        #printf("Grab mode = {}", format(gm))

    cv2.namedWindow("test", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    img_counter = 0
    img_paths = []

    while True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if not ret:
            print("failed to grab frame")
            break
        cv2.imshow("test", frame)
        cv2.resizeWindow("test",1280,720)
        cv2.moveWindow("test",1920,0)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k%256 == 27:
            # ESC pressed
            print("Escape hit, closing...")
            break
        elif k%256 == 32:
            # SPACE pressed
            img_name = "capture_{}.png".format(img_counter)
            img_path = os.path.join(capture_path, img_name)
            img_paths.append(img_path)
            os.makedirs(capture_path, exist_ok=True)
            cv2.imwrite(img_path, frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
            print("{} written!".format(img_name))
            img_counter += 1

    cam.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return img_paths
```

I suspect the exact line I need to alter is this one.

```
            cv2.imwrite(img_path, frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION, 0])
```

As you can see, I have opted for PNG format, which should not result in any JPEG-like compression artifacts.   Despite this selection, I get artifacts.

I have also tried embracing JPEG and setting the quality to max.  This does not improve matters:

```
        cv2.imwrite(img_path, frame, [cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 100])
```

What can I do?  Please and thank you

Comment: I don't know the IPEVO at all, so I may be barking up the wrong tree. Some cameras (such as the Raspberry Pi) have 2 modes - a stills mode and a video mode. In stills mode, they oversample and run much more demanding and more effective noise reduction and produce lower noise, higher resolution output than they would be able to when producing video at 30fps. With **OpenCV** `videocapture()` you are essentially forcing it to behave as a videocamera. Their stills/scan software may take advantage of some ability to act in a more demanding *"stills"* mode. I am only speculating.

Comment: You could maybe try and see if it will allow you to set a lower frame rate and/or a lower ISO (sensitivity/gain) or a longer exposure time and see if that helps.

Comment: Or maybe you could oversample yourself and read, say 5 or more, frames and take the median at each pixel... I assume your document is stationary.

Comment: Great ideas, Mark.  I'll dig in to these.